PySpark: Filtering a Lag for Date Differences
I have a table of field values and dates stored as a PySpark dataframe.  What is the most sensible way in PySpark to add an additional column, that contains the date difference between each row and the most recent row that has the same field value?  For a simple difference of consecutive rows, the answer is obviously the application of a "lag" function, but I am unsure of the most sensible way to apply a filter based on the specific field value in a row.
Example input:
1111| 23/May/2024
2222| 20/May/2024
3333| 19/May/2024
1111| 16/May/2024
4444| 12/May/2024
1111| 07/May/2024
2222| 01/May/2024

Desired Ouput:
1111| 23/May/2024| 7
2222| 20/May/2024| 19
3333| 19/May/2024| default
1111| 16/May/2024| 9
4444| 12/May/2024| default
1111| 07/May/2024| default
2222| 01/May/2024| default


I would think the first step is to set your window, partition by ID and order by date ascending.  Then apply the lag.
set your window over ID and sort by date.  Using with column and using a lag function you can move the date to the next line where it matches your partition.  That should give you the dates side by side under the new column name.  Then you could use another DF to do the math on the two columns?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html

You can achieve the desired result using the lag function as below.
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, datediff, when, col, lit

data = [
    (1111, "2024-05-23"),
    (2222, "2024-05-20"),
    (3333, "2024-05-19"),
    (1111, "2024-05-16"),
    (4444, "2024-05-12"),
    (1111, "2024-05-07"),
    (2222, "2024-05-01"),
]
# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "start"])
df.show()

+----+----------+
|  id|     start|
+----+----------+
|1111|2024-05-23|
|2222|2024-05-20|
|3333|2024-05-19|
|1111|2024-05-16|
|4444|2024-05-12|
|1111|2024-05-07|
|2222|2024-05-01|
+----+----------+

df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "previous_start", lag("start").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start"))
    )
    .withColumn(
        "datediff",
        when(
            col("previous_start").isNotNull(),
            datediff(col("start"), col("previous_start")),
        ).otherwise(lit("default")),
    )
    .drop("previous_start")
    .orderBy(col("start").desc())
)
df.show()

+----+----------+--------+
|  id|     start|datediff|
+----+----------+--------+
|1111|2024-05-23|       7|
|2222|2024-05-20|      19|
|3333|2024-05-19| default|
|1111|2024-05-16|       9|
|4444|2024-05-12| default|
|1111|2024-05-07| default|
|2222|2024-05-01| default|
+----+----------+--------+


